# where to place default value parameter in variable-length function in c++?

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value, variable-length

in variable-length parameters function, the '...' must be place last. And default value enabled parameters must be last, too.

so, how about both needed in the same one function?

Now I have a log utility:
void MyPrint(int32_t logLevel, const char *format, ...), which used to print log according to 'logLevel'.

However, sometimes I hope it can be used as: 
MyPrint("Log test number%d", number), without 'logLevel' needed.

The question:
[Default arguments and variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130613/default-arguments-and-variadic-functions)
didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default arguments and variadic functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130613/default-arguments-and-variadic-functions)

Comment: Curious as to why you need to have variable-length parameter lists and default values... You should be able to come up with a solution that uses one or the other.

Comment: The specific solution for what you want to do with `MyPrint()` would be to have two overloads.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what were the results? Code please. And compiler output.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you might just want make two versions of MyPrint, like:

```
MyPrint(const char *format, ...)
{
    _logLevel = 1;
    // stuff
}
MyPrint(int32_t logLevel, const char *format, ...)
{
    _logLevel = logLevel;
    //stuff
}
```

On the other hand the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-parameter-idiom.html) would indeed provide an alternative solution:

```
class Abc
{
public:
MyPrint(const char *format, ...)
{
    _logLevel = 1;
    // stuff
}
Abc &setLogLevel(int32_t logLevel)
{
    _logLevel = logLevel;
}

// stuff
```

};

So you could call MyPrint() like this:

```
MyPrint("blah,blah", 123);
```

or like this:

```
MyPrint("blah,blah", 123).setLogLevel(5);
```